# Why can't the date correctly be displayed on the X-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

Code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

data <- read.csv("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/full_data.csv")
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
class(data$date)

data$location <- as.character(data$location)

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = date, y = total_cases, color = location)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: you are using ggplotly? The plot above seems to be that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you search for `scale_x_date` and use it to customize the date labels.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. It works. However, I met new issues with the left y-axis. It shows like the screenshot below, while what I need is a ten-based logarithmic label. Do you have an idea with that?

Comment: Hi, Peter. Sure: try adding `+ scale_y_log10()` or use the `trans = "log"` option within `scale_y_continuous`. Check out [this page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) for illustrations.